# How to read/load whole directory via PHP

Tags: php, directory, gallery

I´m am a novice in PHP and to better understand I will explain my problem in example. Imagine we want want to make basic photo gallery that reads photos from directory, but we don´t want to write `<img src="dir/photo/img0.jpg>` into code each time when we will add a new photos in this folder so we just want to add a picture into this folder and this picture will be shown automatically in html code.

The result should be just read the whole directory with images and these images will be shown in html code.

I don´t know how to explain it simplier, I hope that explanation will help. Please ask a question and I will be more specific.

As I said, I´m a novice in PHP and I really want to learn PHP well so any solid code helps.

Thak you a lot.

Comment: http://php.net/glob http://php.net/foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) will out put the directory contents into an array which you will need to loop through to build your images.

```
 $files = scandir('dir/images');
 foreach($files as $file)
 {
      echo "<img src='dir/images/".$file."'/>";
 }
```